# Windows 8 universal authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, owin, windows-8.1-universal

I have an MVC5 application in which I use Owin to authentiate users,
now I'm trying to create a Windows 8 app for this application. But I can't find the best why to implement authentication. I found two possible solutions "Web Authentication Broker" and "Credential Locker" but I'm not sure yet

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    var requestContent = string.Format("UserLogin={0}&UserPassword={1}", userName, password);
    HttpContent content = new StringContent(requestContent);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri((string)ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["LoginApiUrl"]), content);
    });
    task.Wait(); // Wait

    var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var deserializedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(responseData);

    if (deserializedResponse.ContainsKey("success") && Convert.ToBoolean(deserializedResponse["success"]))
    {
        LoadData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you formulate a precise question? And what is the code snippet for that you provided?

Comment: thank you for your response, my question is "what is the best manner for handling authentication between a windows 8 app and mvc 5 application?"